# Access rights for users of "Members" group?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a test user account, who is in the group "Members" with the default permission level of "Contribute". I created two custom aspx pages in Visual Studio, that are stored in the _layouts directory. How is it possible that this user account can view one of those pages, but not the other? One page has a single button on it and the other has a gridview, displaying list items. He can view the page with the gridview, but not the page with a single button. Anyone has an idea why?
Oh, and he is also prohibited from viewing a custom web-part written in Visual Studio, for some reason.

Comment: additional information would be helpful.  What does the page with a single button do, i.e. are there any errors thrown?  Also have you checked the ULS logs for additional details?

Comment: It adds and removes the current user from a certain group. No errors are thrown, it just says "access denied", and not upon firing the button event, but upon trying to enter the page. There is no way SharePoint actually pre-compiles all the code on an aspx page to see what the code does, is there?

Comment: I didn't check the logs, i would appreciate the info of what they are and where I can view them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok based on your comments it sounds like you are probably accessing either the Group itself and the current user doesn't have access to view the members of the group.  Note it may also be something else in your code behind that the current user doesn't have permission to do.  Typically the access denied page happens without an exception so you'll have to look at the SharePoint ULS logs for more information on the error.  (Technically it aborts the normal page rendering life cycle and redirects the user to the Access Denied page.)

ULS logs are found in the 12 hive under the `LOGS` subdirectory.  I would suggest using the [ULS Viewer](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer/) instead of trying to visually parse through the logs with NotePad (there's a lot there).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, one more question, if you don't mind - what is the general policy for users accessing custom aspx pages - are the contents of these pages actually being analyzed before the user is granted access?

Comment: Pages under the Layouts folder don't have access privileges associated with them (although controls may be security trimmed; SharePoint has a control for this).  You, the developer, will be responsible for checking permissions that apply to your custom page and altering the page as appropriate.  Note that the page lifecycle will execute under the user's credentials so if you try to do something on their behalf SharePoint may give you an exception or Access Denied page.